# Getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when running an application

Tags: linux, redhat, java

I am on a linux Red Hat machine and am trying to run a shell script that initiates a java application. It ran just fine yesterday but today I am getting this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.<clinit>(Reference.java:162)
```

free -m

```
total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15951      14754       1196         66        217       3208
-/+ buffers/cache:      11328       4622
Swap:        15999          0      15999
```

I've done a bunch of reading on this issue but I'm not sure how to solve it on my system. It seems to be a system resources issue. can anyone help?

Comment: Well, it appears that you're out of memory. Please edit your question and post the output of `free -m`.

Comment: @EEAA Just did. memory seems fine.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the amount of RAM available to the JVM?

Comment: @EEAA no but from the output of free -m it doesn't seem like I need to do that do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult question for us to answer because we don't know what your program does.  Bottom line though is that `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` is often caused by either spikes in traffic on your app or a memory leak.

You should play around with the two java flags that specify the memory allocation pools for the Java Virtual Machine:`-Xmx`(maximum memory allocated) and `-Xms` (initial memory allocated)

Play around with the numbers and see what works.  If you see the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` error, then just increase the memory numbers and restart your java process.

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying `-Xmx128m` when instantiating the JVM. Try increasing that value.

Comment: What would be a good value to set that at?

Comment: There's no possible way for me to help you answer that. You'll need to experiment and see what is good for *your* application with *your* workload.

Comment: And can I get rid of _JAVA_OPTIONS all together?

Comment: That's quite unlikely. And why would you want to do so?

Comment: What does the app do?  Does it connect to a database and fetch work to do. Maybe change it to 256 and see if it starts.

It's possible it's bringing back too much to store in memory.

Comment: @davey it connect me to a weblogic server. you mean change -Xmx to 256?

Comment: @EEAA I want to do that because that's something I set myself and before I did so I did not get the 'Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS' error. It seems to be putting limitations on my JVM.

Comment: @user348617 Don't over-think this. You have plenty of spare RAM on the machine. Set it to something high, and then you can decrease it as needed, once you have a better idea of how much RAM it consumes.

Comment: @user348617 This is how the JVM works. There's a reason it's called the "Java Virtual Machine". It's akin to a separate operating system with its own memory management, process management, etc. That's a drastic simplification, but for your case, it's OK to think about it in this manner.

Comment: @EEAA export _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms64m -Xmx300m -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd  is giving me a bunch of "not a valid identifier" errors

Comment: @user348617 I'd recommend that you read the documentation so that you understand things before making changes. The documentation clearly says that Xmx must be a multiple of 1024bytes. So 128m, 256m, 512m, etc.

Comment: @EEAA export _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms64m -Xmx256m -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-bash: export: `_JAVA_OPTIONS:': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `-Xms64m': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `-Xmx256m': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd': not a valid identifier

Comment: Well, you're flailing around now trying to get this sorted out, and formatting these messages in comments is an exercise in futility. You have your answer. Sorting out how you managed to muck things up is another problem altogether. Perhaps you munged something when you edited that line.

Comment: @EEAA the problem is not  _JAVA_OPTIONS. _Java_OPTIONS was set only for my last session. I ended that session and logged back into my machine and i'm still getting the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread error.

Comment: Please edit your question, including **everything** you've changed.

Comment: @EEAA please edit your answer so that it shows me how to set my _JAVA_OPTIONS to a higher number.

Comment: That depends completely on how your application is set up. We're not here to do your job for you - you'll need to research how to do this on your own.

Answer (score 0):

check max open files set for the user. You may need to increase that. use pidstat for the rpocessid (pidstat -h -r -u -p $javapid | grep -v "Command") and no of processes running (ps aux | grep 'java ' | grep "application name" | grep -v grep | wc -l). MUP (Max user process) set for the user is important.

Comment: If the open files limit was reached, there would be a different exception/error thrown, not an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: OOM: unable to create new native thread is for MUP setting issue. This is nothing to do with Heap space. I have faced this issue in our application ans sorted by setting right MUP